# Ui router Keep page template when changing route to map state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to change the route of my url to open a map overlay. The problem is when I switch states, the page template underneath switches as well. I don't want this to happen.

I am using `$statechange` to detect the map route and executing an `event.preventDefault();` which should stop the route template from changing. But in my case, the map url gets put in the address bar and then quickly gets removed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using the $state.go and declaring options 'notify' to false.. This stops the $stateroute changes to fire.

Answer (score 0):

It seems counterintuitive to override the state change. Why don't you create the overlay as a child state and just navigate to it normally.

Comment: Overlay can be opened on all child states.